# Parallel.ForEach, limit simultaneous connections

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.foreach

I have a collection of files and I need to process them in parallel. The processing includes uploading each file to an FTP-server as a final step. The number of simultaneous connections on that server is limited, let's say, to 2. I use `Parallel.Foreach()` like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, options, ProcessFile);
```

Do I guarantee by passing to `Parallel.ForEach`

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
```

that I won't exceed the number of allowed connections? I've read a lot about how `Parallel.ForEach` works , but I am still not sure. I consider the case that I am the only one user of FTP-server and every connection is closed properly during `ProcessFile`.

Comment: The limit on connections: is that *total* connections? or is it "per calling node" connections? If the former, you'd need to be very sure that it isn't running anywhere else. In the latter, you'd still need to know whether this *operation* could be done twice at once in your application.

Comment: @MarcGravell Total. Each call opens a new connection and close it after file was uploaded.

Comment: My point there ("total") is : do you know that your application is only running on one node?

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually, the question is: if the collection consist of 1000 files, is that possible that threads open more than 2 connections? Only one application is running.

Comment: @QuéPadre No it won't if you closed the connection properly at end of ProcessFile method

Comment: @QuéPadre if you can guarantee that it is only running once in the process, and the process isn't running more than once, then yes: that should be sufficient.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is that possible that 2 threads start processing 2 files, open 2 connections, and then one of the threads switches to third file processing before finishing the whole operation?

Comment: @QuéPadre that would be a violation of the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, so in theory: no. If you are worried - semaphore is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will ensure you have at most two tasks running at the same time. Assuming that no other process or task is doing any uploads to that server, you should be fine.

I would suggest to use a semaphore inside your foreach loop instead, because then the actual processing can be done with more than two tasks at the same time. This improves performance if the processing is the part that takes most time.

Comment: I am doing exactly this way. All the steps of processing run in parallel, but when it comes to upload I use a semaphore.